# Fastest way to delete a range of elements

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs. If the list exceeds 100, I want to keep only the last 100 items and delete (remove) all the items that precede the last 100. I don't want to call the jQuery "remove" method x number of times if possible as this could be a performance issue. I thought I might be able to use the splice method but that doesn't work:

```
$(divList.children()).splice(0, divList.children().length - 100);
```

Any other suggestions?

*EDIT*: My question doesn't seem to be clear as every answer below results in selecting the items to be deleted and calling the remove method on that selection. That results in the remove method being called each time for each div to be deleted. I want to avoid that, hence the solution I posted above that I thought would delete the entire array range in one swoop. I am looking for a solution that does not use the remove method.

Comment: You can something like `divList.children().filter(':lt(' + (divList.children().length - 100) + ')').remove();`

Comment: what error u getting

Comment: I dont understand, why you dont want to use remove method?

Comment: remove has a big performance issue when you have a lot of stuff to remove.

Comment: Splice method will remove element from object, not from DOM,

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the same level, you can try something like

```
$('div:nth-of-type(2) ~ div').remove(); //replace 2 with 100
```

```js
$('div:nth-of-type(2) ~ div').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Here, in the above example, there are five items, and the selector selects all the `div` elements after second `div` element, which in your case would be 100. Rest of it will be removed.

Comment: Would that not essentially be the same thing as calling remove x number of times?

Comment: Op said `keep` last

Comment: @AndroidDev I think you need to do it anyways to remove each of the element.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You wanted the last element right? I mean, am not sure if that's what OP wants.

Comment: @Mr.Alien No, I don't want the last element. Your solution is correct but I believe that remove is called each time for each element. Looking for a faster solution.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have divs 1-5, OP wants to keep 3,4,5

Comment: Now I'm confused - op says `I want to keep only the last 100 items` - not clear

Comment: If I have 150 items, I want to delete the first 50.

Comment: @AndroidDev yes, that's why this is wrong - you have five and want to delete 3, surely 4 & 5 should be left? This answer leaves 1 & 2

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You are getting confused :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien - ha ha I'm not, I don't think - how else can this be interpreted? I've substituted OP numbers for your numbers `I have a list of divs. If the list exceeds 2, I want to keep only the last 2 items and delete (remove) all the items that precede the last 2` - the key for me is `that precede the last 2` - I need a coffee!

Answer (score 0):

Use [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector

It starts in 0

> Description: Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

```js
$( "div:gt(2)" ).remove( );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: Same as Mr. Alien answer, this is keeping the first, op said keep last

Comment: No, I want to delete all items that precede the last 100 items. Guradio's solution is correct but this would be a performance issue if there were thousands of items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this its very simple***

```
$("div:lt(100)").remove()
```

or else try this.Its fast

```
divlist = $("container")
divlist.children().splice(0,divlist.children().length-100).remove()
```

Comment: That's just a selection. You still have to delete the items. I want to avoid calling the remove method x number of times.

Comment: "lt" is very performance poor. If I have to use the remove method, then I would select using the slice method. See the Additional Notes at http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextUntil()` to achieve this, example:

> $(begin).nextUntil(end)

```js
$("div:eq(0)").nextUntil("div:eq(4)").remove()
$("div:eq(0)").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

You can put it inside a function and call it each time you need to remove a lot divs at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector along with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method

```js
var divList = $(".container").children();
divList.filter(':lt(' + (divList.length - 2) + ')').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

---

As an alternative you can use `splice()` to extract only element which needs to exists and update the container using `.html()`

```js
var container = $(".container");
var divList = container.children();
container.html(divList.splice(divList.length - 2)) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This like the other solutions below causes the remove method to be called each time for each div to be removed. Looking for a higher performance solution as I could have thousands of divs to delete.

Comment: @AndroidDev *I could have thousands of divs to delete* - Your approach is wrong than.